# How can I make an application appear under its own icon, when launched from a script?

Tags: .desktop, launcher

I have a script that launches a number of Google Chrome windows through `wmctrl`. I created a launcher for that script and assigned a different icon to it. Problem is, every time Google Chrome is launched in this way, in window switcher (Alt+Tab) it is assigned the icon of the launcher, not its native one.

Is there a way to set the native Google Chrome icon (or, if we generalize - to keep a native icon of an opened application) when launching it through a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use StartupWMClass in a reversed way

Normally, you can make sure a window *is* connected to a specific launcher (icon) by adding a line (e.g.) `StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable` to the `.desktop` file.

To *prevent* a window from being connected to an icon, the opposite can be done as well: add a line to your custom (script-) launcher:

```
StartupWMClass=Banana
```

To make sure the window, called by the launcher is *not* attached to the launcher, since `Banana` is a none-sense `StartupWMClass`. It will then be connected to its own icon again.